# remove given element in an array using jquery fn extension doesn't work in reference way

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, customization

i wrote jquery custom fn extension script to remove the given element in an array,
but it works unexpected way so i want to figure out how to make it do reference manipulation without using return reference way.

```
$.fn.removeElement=function(e){
    var l=this.length;
    while(l--){
        if(this[l]==e){
            console.log(this);
            this.splice(l,1);
            console.log(this);
            break;
}   }   }
var x=['a','b','c','d','e'];
console.log(x);
$(x).removeElement('c');
console.log(x);
```

result is like the below,

```
> ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
> ["a", "b", "d", "e"]
> ["a", "b", "d", "e"]
> ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"] //???
```

i expect ["a", "b", "d", "e"] in the forth line.

p.s. i don't want 'return stuff'..

Comment: above example was modified to demonstrate the issue more precisely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one, this line of code:

```
if('object'==typeof(e))
```

is like this in your code example:

```
if('object'==typeof(3))
```

which is

```
if('object'=='number')
```

which will never match.

I would also ask why you're trying to wrap a normal array in a jQuery object.  It would be better to just use a method that operates on an array.

As a global function, you could do it like this:

```
function removeArrayElement(array, itemToRemove) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] === itemToRemove) {
            array.splice(i, 1);
            break;
        }
    }
}

var x = ['a','b','c','d','e'];
removeArrayElement(x, 'c');
```

As a global method on the jQuery object, you could do it like this:

```
$.removeArrayElement = function(array, itemToRemove) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] === itemToRemove) {
            array.splice(i, 1);
            break;
        }
    }
}

var x = ['a','b','c','d','e'];
$.removeArrayElement(x, 'c');
```

As a method on the Array object, you could do it like this:

```
Array.prototype.removeElement = function(itemToRemove) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        if (this[i] === itemToRemove) {
            this.splice(i, 1);
            break;
        }
    }
}

var x = ['a','b','c','d','e'];
x.removeElement('c');
```

Working example of the prototype method here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/tEXWH/

Comment: how to wrap up a normal array? can you explain little bit more detail?

Comment: @zannavi - Multiple examples added to my answer.

Comment: prototype solution result in an error in my case, NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8: An attempt was made to reference a Node in a context where it does not exist. (mac osx safari 5.1.3 current version) i have not a clue for that. :(

Comment: @zannavi - You would have to share the code that gives that error.  I don't know what your code is that could cause that error.  The code I offered works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/tEXWH/.

Comment: i don't like function(array,item) method because it doesn't take the advantage of reference concept of the language.

Comment: @zannavi - I offered you several choices because there are pros/cons of each.  Other people don't like adding non-standard methods to the built-in object prototypes because they can conflict with other libraries or other code.  But, it will work just fine.

Comment: okay then, i admit that my exception is hard to reproduce, i'll work around to reproduce that exception, it may be from the confliction of my codes.

Comment: i want to use $(array).removeElement(el) way. is it impossible? that is what i want and the reason i post.

Comment: @zannavi - jQuery is designed to hold arrays of DOM elements and most jQuery methods assume that's what the array holds.  For example, many jQuery methods reorder the array into DOM order at the conclusion of the method.  If you absolutely want it on the jQuery object, then use the second solution I proposed.  I would not recommend using what you are asking for.  I think it will deceive people reading your code and may lead to some problems.

Answer (score 0):

Because of your `if (typeof(e) == "object")`. A number (ex, `3`) isn't an `"object"`. It's a `"number"`.

I should mention, though: be careful when using `$(foo)` when `foo` is an array. jQuery will occasionally do surprising things (depending on the values in the array). Better would be to use `$.removeElement(myArray, toRemove)`.

Comment: you're right. but if an element instead of 3 and a list of elements may result in the same. as you say i think using $(array) is a kind of bad idea. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery already has a `remove` method](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) for its own purposes.

If you want a remove method specifically for the native JavaScript Array object, you should just write the function outside the context of jQuery:

```
Array.prototype.remove = function (el){
  for (var i = 0, j = this.length; i < j; i++){
    if (this[i] == el){
      this.splice(i, 1);
      break;
    }
  }
}

var x = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
console.log(x);    // => [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ]
x.remove('b');
console.log(x);    // => [ 'a', 'c', 'd' ]
```

Comment: is it impossible to use the context of jQuery?
this example result in an error,
NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8: An attempt was made to reference a Node in a context where it does not exist.
(mac osx safari 5.1.3 current version)

Comment: jQuery already has a `remove` method. Do you need something beyond what that method already does? I don't know why you're seeing that error, since that code runs fine in my Safari 5.